# Can I get all the file extensions of text files in the repository in CVS?

Tags: list, text, file, types, cvs

I need a list of all file types of text files in CVS (such as *.cpp,*.h etc. )

can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quick and dirty but you can play with regular expressions, grepping, redirecting to a file, sorting...(blah blah blah):

```
cvs ls -R [path to repo] | grep "\.[A-Za-z0-9]*$" | sed 's/.*\(\.[A-Za-z0-9]*\)$/\1/' > fileExtensions && sort fileExtensions | uniq
```

Explanation:

- list all files in the repository
- print only those with an extension
- extract the extension with sed
- redirect output to a file
- sort the file, then print unique lines

Comment: You're assuming he's using Linux

Comment: Yeah, or any decent *NIX OS (Solaris, BSD, etc.)

Comment: @Scoregraphic: there is no assumption about Linux or *nix.  The only assumption is the existence of the tools grep, sed, cvs, and uniq and the syntax for piping and redirecting output.